# Gitlab CI set up django postgres service

Tags: python, django, postgresql, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am facing this service for hours but still I do not have solutions. My gitlab.yml looks like this

```
image: python:3.6

services:
  -  postgres:latest


variables:
  POSTGRES_DB: test
  POSTGRES_USER: postgres
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ""
  POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust

job:on-schedule:
  only:
    - schedules

  script:
    - export DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:@postgres:5432/test
    - apt-get -yq update
    - apt-get -yq install python-pip
    - pip install -r requirements.txt
    - python manage.py test
```

and settings

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'test',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'postgres',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}
```

at first I have come about a connection error like is it listening to 5432 and locally etc.

Now I am facing time out. All processes passed when it comes to the `python manage.py test` it does not run next. I do not know why. Please anybody can help??? Thanks in advance